# Gmail smtp does not send my emails

Tags: php

I am trying to send an email with Gmail smtp, but I dont send any mail. 
Neither do I receive any errors, I just get an empty page. 
Here is my code, I hope you can help me with this.

```
<?php 
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "MyEmail";
$mail->Password = "Mypassword";
$mail->setFrom('MyEmail');
$mail->addReplyTo('MyEmail');
$mail->addAddress('MyEmail');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->Body = 'This is a plain-text message body';
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Please note that I entered the correct emails and passwords.

Comment: Are u running this local or on a server? If it's the first it could be that the port is blocked

Comment: No I am not running it on a local server. But if it would be blocked shouldn't I receive a error?

Comment: try by putting a wrong password and username to see if you get any error. if you get an error, next thing would be to check the php_info(); to see if is there any sendemail application installed. also check that error_reporting(E_ALL); and the display_errors=On

Comment: I added error_reporting(E_ALL); and got aa fatal error: **Fatal error: Class 'smtp' not found in /srv/www/pubs/test/class.phpmailer.php on line 1194**, I looked it up in the file: $this->smtp = new SMTP;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default PHPMailer will send mail using php's `mail()` function (sendmail). You need to include `smtp` class for phpMailer to able to send mail using SMTP

```
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';
```

you can get it from [github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php)

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue that he didn't echo'd anything. I got a new issue where i will look into.